# React Convert HTML to Component and pass extra props

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using `[svg-inline-loader][1]` to inline SVG Images in my React Application.

When I import an SVG, the webpack module passes it to the variable as an HTML string. I need to convert this string into a React Component so that I can pass additional props to it.

My current code looks like this

```
import SVGlogo from './logo.svg';

export default () => (
  <a href="/" className="navbar-item is-purple" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: SVGlogo }} /> 
);
```

This works fine but I need to pass additional attributes/props to `SVGlogo`. Is there a way I can do this elegantly without manually modifying the string and adding attributes to it.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to built an own non class component for your SVG stuff and then import it into the section / HOC component.

See my example here:

[image: Edit oxkw07qpqz]

Greetings!